# How to enter developer information for a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

How do I enter developer info for a shiny app as done in the app on this site: https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/brazil-voter-profile.html. I'll insert an image attached for you to see too.

From what I saw in their app code, they used R Markdown in this part of the developers' description, but I would like something that could be done without needing R Mardown, any ideas or could you help me?

Below is a structure of a code for you to use.

Thank you so much guys!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)

ui <- shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
                        title="Test", collapsible = TRUE,
                        
                        tabPanel("Developers",
                                 
                       br(),
                           
                       p(a("Jose Souza", href="www.josesouza.com", target="_blank"),style = "font-size:25px"),
                       p("e-mail: jojo.souza.1208.com",style = "font-size:20px"),
                        )

                        )



server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

**How I wish:**

[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Karsten, I just managed to put the name and an access link (I adjusted the code and inserted an image above). The rest I couldn't, that is, leave in the format: a picture of me on the left side and a description on the right side.

Comment: [This could help](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html), use some `fluidRow` with `columns` of the desired width.